Slow-cooking venison for tenderness before adding to stew
Someone gave me some venison that they labeled "stew meat", I am not sure what exact part of the deer it was. I want to cook it in a bean-based stew, sortof a central European style recipe with paprika. I usually cook a stew like that when without meat for an hour but I am skeptical if that will be long enough to tenderize the venison. I've cooked it before and it had varying degrees of toughness. I had success before slow cooking wild turkey legs for a really long time and was able to get them tender that way.
My question is, should I slow-cook venison for maybe 4-5 hrs on low and then add it to cook with the stew for like an hour, in order to achieve tenderness?
